# avaudiorecorder showing a delay of 3 second before starting recording

Tags: iphone, ios5, xcode4.2

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Delay in Recording using avaudiorecorder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7804177/delay-in-recording-using-avaudiorecorder)

I am running an app on Xcode4 using ios5 and facing a problem there is a delay of 3 sec from pressing the record button to actually start recording. I have searched every where and havent found any good solution for me.

Here is the code

```
    -(void) recordBtnClick:(UIButton *)sender

  {    

      if (!recordBtn && !playBtn)
        {   
           NSLog(@"recording pressed");

           [recordButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"stop.png"]               forState:UIControlStateNormal];

           recordBtn=YES;

         //startRecording;

       // Init audio with record capability
       AVAudioSession *audioSession = [AVAudioSession sharedInstance];
         [audioSession setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryRecord error:nil];

        NSMutableDictionary *recordSettings = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]  initWithCapacity:10];

     if(recordEncoding == ENC_PCM)
       {
        [recordSettings setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt: kAudioFormatLinearPCM] forKey: AVFormatIDKey];
        [recordSettings setObject:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:16000.0] forKey: AVSampleRateKey];
        [recordSettings setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:2] forKey:AVNumberOfChannelsKey];
        [recordSettings setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:16] forKey:AVLinearPCMBitDepthKey];
        [recordSettings setObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:NO] forKey:AVLinearPCMIsBigEndianKey];
        [recordSettings setObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:NO] forKey:AVLinearPCMIsFloatKey];   
    }
    else
    {
        NSNumber *formatObject;

        switch (recordEncoding) {
            case (ENC_AAC): 
                formatObject = [NSNumber numberWithInt: kAudioFormatMPEG4AAC];
                break;
            case (ENC_ALAC):
                formatObject = [NSNumber numberWithInt: kAudioFormatAppleLossless];
                break;
            case (ENC_IMA4):
                formatObject = [NSNumber numberWithInt: kAudioFormatAppleIMA4];
                break;
            case (ENC_ILBC):
                formatObject = [NSNumber numberWithInt: kAudioFormatiLBC];
                break;
            case (ENC_ULAW):
                formatObject = [NSNumber numberWithInt: kAudioFormatULaw];
                break;
            default:
                formatObject = [NSNumber numberWithInt: kAudioFormatAppleIMA4];
        }

        [recordSettings setObject:formatObject forKey: AVFormatIDKey];
        [recordSettings setObject:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:44100.0] forKey: AVSampleRateKey];
        [recordSettings setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:2] forKey:AVNumberOfChannelsKey];
        [recordSettings setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:12800] forKey:AVEncoderBitRateKey];
        [recordSettings setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:16] forKey:AVLinearPCMBitDepthKey];
        [recordSettings setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt: AVAudioQualityHigh] forKey: AVEncoderAudioQualityKey];
    }
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *recDir = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/audio%d.wav",recDir,nextCount]];

    NSError *error = nil;
    audioRecorder = [[ AVAudioRecorder alloc] initWithURL:url settings:recordSettings error:&error];
    audioRecorder.delegate=self;
    if(!audioRecorder){
        NSLog(@"recorder: %@ %d %@", [error domain], [error code], [[error userInfo] description]);
        UIAlertView *alert =
        [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle: @"Warning"
                                   message: [error localizedDescription]
                                  delegate: nil
                         cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                         otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alert show];
        [alert release];
        return;
    }

    //prepare to record
    [audioRecorder prepareToRecord];
   //audioRecorder.meteringEnabled = YES;

    BOOL audioHWAvailable = audioSession.inputIsAvailable;
    if (! audioHWAvailable) {
        UIAlertView *cantRecordAlert =
        [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle: @"Warning"
                                   message: @"Audio input hardware not available"
                                  delegate: nil
                         cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                         otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [cantRecordAlert show];
        [cantRecordAlert release]; 
        return;
    }
    [audioRecorder recordForDuration:(NSTimeInterval) 25];


    NSLog(@"recording");
    // ---------------- record code finished ----------------//
  }else{
    [recordButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"record.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    recordBtn=NO;
    [audioRecorder stop];
    AVAudioSession *audioSession = [AVAudioSession sharedInstance];
    [audioSession setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback error:nil];


  }

 }
```

Comment: Don't just re-post your question without adding any additional information.  Address the concerns brought up in the comments from the first time you asked this.

Comment: actually the eariler one was closed , and i didnt get any help form that so i decided to open a new question .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do the prepare to record and all the initialization required before it before displaying your app's record button.

Comment: its a page based app so i have to record sound on every page uniquely, for that i have to call the initialization process every time user touch the record button!

Comment: No need to duplicate the audio session or record initialization code.

Comment: if i initialize record code in applicationDidFinishLunching or viewDidLoad method, the only first time i can record the sound after that it does record anything.